# Insert Variables in schema org json format

Tags: json, variables, schema.org, json-ld

for a website I set up schema org, written all in hand, something like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@graph": [
          {
            "@type": "MedicalOrganization",
            "@id": "https://example.com/#medicalorganization",
            "isAcceptingNewPatients": "True",
........
</script>
```

The question ist:

It is possible to insert variables in json? So that not everything is hardcoded? For example for the url:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@graph": [
          {
            "@type": "MedicalOrganization",
            "@id": "{{variables.url}}/#medicalorganization",
            "isAcceptingNewPatients": "True",
```

Is there a easy way, also regarding the web performance?

I try import a varibales.js file, but not can access them in the .json format